# jquery lightbox 0.5 giving error for hidden links. How to fix it?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm using jquery-lightbox-0.5
http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/
Calling like this

```
$('.zoomLightbox a').lightBox();
```

Html

```
<p class="zoomLightbox">
<a rel="lightbox" class="zoomPhoto" title="abc" href="images/products/lightbox-zoom-placeholder.gif">View larger photo</a>
<a style="display: none;" rel="lightbox" class="zoomPhoto hide" title="abc" href="images/products/lightbox-zoom-placeholder.gif">View larger photo</a>
...
</p>
```

Except first link rest are hidden. Now issue is that when moving to second img and then back to first prev link is still active and onclicking prev link its giving this error.

```
settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage] is undefined
[Break On This Error] objImagePreloader.src = settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage][0];
```

I'm stuck here any help appreciated.

Its hapening only when fixedNavigation: true

Answer (score 1):

I think you should modify the plugin

Go to line 194

```
objImagePreloader.src = settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage][0]
```

change to

```
if (settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage]) {
                objImagePreloader.src = settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage][0];
            }
            else {
                _finish();
                return false;
            }
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

See this [post](http://warren.mesozen.com/2007/09/17/jquery-lightbox-version-03/), and read the comments added at the end part.

**:: UPDATE ::**
Dude, I have implemented the example based on your given sample code, and its working fine at my end....

Html code :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.zoomLightbox a').lightBox();
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p class="zoomLightbox">
                <a rel="lightbox" class="zoomPhoto" title="abc" href="img_1.png">View larger photo</a>
                <a style="display: none;" rel="lightbox" class="zoomPhoto hide" title="abc" href="img_2.png">View larger photo</a>
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And following is the project structure :

[image]

Just cross check your code with above, and make sure you have proper includes of the required js and css files...

Comment: It is not working for me...when I inspect through firebug I found that lightbox-nav-btnPrev is with display: none but in my case it's not. I'm not able to find how its done

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missing `<img />` tags. According to the plug-in documentation, your markup should look like this:

```
<p class="zoomLightbox">
<a rel="lightbox" class="zoomPhoto">
  <img title="abc" src="images/products/lightbox-zoom-placeholder.gif" />
  View larger photo
</a>
<a style="display: none;" rel="lightbox" class="zoomPhoto hide" >
  <img title="abc" src="images/products/lightbox-zoom-placeholder.gif" />
  View larger photo
</a>
...
</p>
```

**Edit**: I realized that `<img>`s are not mandatory for the plugin. Please wait as I update this answer.